# Oracle Partition Insert/Update Metadata?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

As an optimisation strategy we're looking into using Oracle Partition Metadata to identity which partitions have had rows inserted/updated in the last 24 hours. We want to process the changed partitions only.

Would anyone know if such metadata exists for a partition?

Thanks,
Dáire

Comment: do you have a timestamp column in your table? If so, you could use that to work it out.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for information that would tell you what partitions had updates in the last 24 hours.  I don't believe there is anything which tells you that specifically.  But, look at the following two views.  user_tab_partitions and user_tab_modifications.  Search and read up on what they can provide.

Comment: What "processing" are you trying to perform?

Comment: We're sqooping changes/deltas to a Hadoop cluster for ETL (table is 1.2B rows), Thinking of attempting to target specific partitions and only sqoop those to speed up the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with metadata, as opposed to building your own monitoring (with a trigger or a timestamp column or a materialized view or something), then I think the answer is *sort of*.

If you enable monitoring for your partitioned table, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE my_partitioned_tab MONITORING;
```

, then Oracle will keep track of the number of updates against the table and against each individual partition.  This information becomes visible in `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`.

However, the `TIMESTAMP` column in that view is the timestamp when the data was flush and the data is only flushed on demand or when statistics are gathered or when the instance is shutdown or "every so often" (varies by release).

Flushing on demand is done as follows:

```
BEGIN DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO; END;
```

After flushing you can see the data in `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`:

```
select partition_name, timestamp
from dba_tab_modifications
where table_name = 'MY_PARTITIONED_TAB';
```

But, in Oracle 12c anyway, the `TIMESTAMP` will be the time when the data was flushed, not the time that the modification happened.  (Oracle's documentation of this table is inaccurate / misleading on this point).

So, bottom line, if you can reliably flush the monitoring every, say, 10 minutes, you should be able to get a close approximation of which partitions were modified in the last 24 hours (+/- 10 minutes).

Comment: I'll dig into this, it looks promising. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Partition Change Tracking** ([PCT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/advmv.htm#DWHSG00324))
to identify the modified partition.

The only think you need is to setup very simple materialized view containing either your prtition key or [PMARKER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm#i997068) on your partitioned table.
(please see other [requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/advmv.htm#DWHSG00324) to enable PCT)

The PCT feature tracks the base table of the MV (i.e. your partitioned table) and flags the modified partition as `STALE`
(i.e. partitions that must be rereshed in the MV). You may access this ifromation using the dictionary view `USER_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION`

**Example**

*setup of partitioned table and the PCT MV*

```
CREATE TABLE  tp 
   ("NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
      "SAMPLE_MINUTE" DATE
   )
PARTITION BY RANGE (SAMPLE_MINUTE)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-03-2017','DD-MM-YYYY'))
); 


insert into tp  (NAME, SAMPLE_MINUTE) values ('xx', to_date('01012017','ddmmyyyy'));
commit;
 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TPM
refresh complete on demand with primary key
AS
select DBMS_MVIEW.PMARKER(rowid) pm, count(*) cnt
from tp
group by DBMS_MVIEW.PMARKER(rowid);
```

*now, let's check the MV metadata*

```
select DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME, DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION, FRESHNESS
from USER_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION where MVIEW_NAME = 'TPM';

DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME          DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION FRESHNESS
------------------------------ ------------------------- ---------
PART_01                                                1 FRESH
```

*So, this is the initial stat, we have one partition, which is fresh. Let add an other record in the same partition..*

```
insert into tp  (NAME, SAMPLE_MINUTE) values ('yy', to_date('01012017','ddmmyyyy')); 
commit;

select DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME, DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION, FRESHNESS  
from USER_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION where MVIEW_NAME = 'TPM'; 

DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME          DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION FRESHNESS
------------------------------ ------------------------- ---------
PART_01                                                1 STALE
```

*as expected the partition is now stale. So now we add a new record in other partition (note that I use interval partitioning, so the partition will be created automatically)*

```
insert into tp  (NAME, SAMPLE_MINUTE) values ('yy', to_date('03032017','ddmmyyyy'));
commit;

select DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME, DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION, FRESHNESS  
from USER_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION where MVIEW_NAME = 'TPM'; 

DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME          DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION FRESHNESS
------------------------------ ------------------------- ---------
PART_01                                                1 STALE     
SYS_P9341                                              2 STALE
```

*Still OK, now we have two stale partitions*

If you want to reset the state (i.e. after running the job processing the changed partitions) simple refresh the materialized view and all partitions will be `FRESH` again

```
exec dbms_mview.REFRESH( LIST => 'TPM',  method => 'P',  atomic_refresh => FALSE);

select DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME, DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION, FRESHNESS  
from USER_MVIEW_DETAIL_PARTITION where MVIEW_NAME = 'TPM';

DETAIL_PARTITION_NAME          DETAIL_PARTITION_POSITION FRESHNESS
------------------------------ ------------------------- ---------
PART_01                                                1 FRESH     
SYS_P9341                                              2 FRESH
```

Note that you are using PCT to refresh the MV (method = 'P'), so only the *stale* partitions will be reagreagted.

The refresh of the MV resets the changes state; you can controll this fully as required - once per 24 hours or on demand after executiong the job processing the changes.